# Кнопка перехода в другое приложение

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Нне нужна кнопка, при нажатии на которую происходит переход в другое iOS приложение. Как ее сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если стороннее приложение поддерживает кастомные урлы (т.е. вида `myap://`), то это делается так:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myapp://link"]];
```

Кнопку сами сделаете)

Comment: Под кастомными урлами имеется ввиду схемы, это поможет гуглить.